# Convert 2D function to 1D function

Tags: c++11, math, lambda, linear-algebra, std-function

For Education Purposes

I have a function which takes the derivative of a given input function.

```
//In analysis class 
double analysis::differentiateBest(std::function<double(double)> fn, double x)
{
    return derivative_1_Richardson_6O(fn,  x);
}
```

The way I call this function is by using a lambda in place of the std::function

```
analysis al;
std::cout << al.differentiateBest([](double x) { return x*x*x*x*x*x; }, 2)
```

I want to extend the derivative to Higher Dimension. ie.Take a gardient.

```
// matrix<T> my class for holding matrices , implemented as 1D std::vector
matrix<double> analysis::gradient_2D(std::function<double(double, double)> fn,double x, double y)
{
    matrix<double> R(2, 1);

//DOUBT
    std::function<double(double xVar)> fnX = fn( xVar, y); //ERROR
    // creates a new fn which holds y constant and allows x to vary  

    std::function<double(double yVar)> fnY = fn( x, yVar); //ERROR
    // creates a new fn which holds x constant and allows y to vary 

    R(1, 1) = differentiateBest(fnX,x); // Takes derivative in X direction , holding y constant 
    R(1, 2) = differentiateBest(fnY,y);  // Takes derivative in Y direction , holding x constant 

return R; 
}
```

So the way I will call gradient is

```
analysis al; 
matrix<double> R = al.gradient_2D([](double x,double y) { return x*x*x*y + y; }, 2 ,3) ; 
// Takes the gradient of lambda function at the point  2 , 3
```

This is what I want to do. But I get error in VS at this line

```
    std::function<double(double xVar)> fnX = fn( xVar, y); 
    std::function<double(double yVar)> fnY = fn( x, yVar);
```

I want to make the 2D function into a 1D function , by fixing the x or y value. 
The x or y values are fixed at the point at which we want to take the gradient.

So my question is how can I convert a std::function taking 2 variables into a function taking a single variable .

PS- I know it will be easier to use a library , but I would like to learn to do this myself , hence educational at top . 
-Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda to the rescue:

```
std::function<double(double)> fnX =
 [fn,y](double xVar){
   return fn( xVar, y);
 };
```

this generates an anonymous callable object that takes one `double` and returns one `double`.  (the return type is deduced from the return type of `fn`)

The syntax for lambda is `[` capture-list `](` argument-list `)` optional `->` then return type `{` code `}`.  It creates an object of an unnamable type that, when invoked with the argument-list, runs the code and returns whatever the code returned.  They are very useful.

The conceptual problem was that `xVar` does *not* name anything on that line.  `std::function<double(double xVar)>` the `xVar` there is discarded, and does not "mean" anything other than documentation.

So the later `xVar` on the same line is thus not connected to any meaning.  With the lambda above, we bind `xVar` to an argument of the function object, which can then be converted into a `std::function<double(double)>`.

The `yVar` case I leave as an exercise to the asker.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `std::bind` to bind the fixed parameters.  This will produce a partially applied function you can pass the remaining argument into.

You example should probably look something like:

```
std::function<double(double)> fnX = std::bind(fn, std::placeholders::_1, y);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I am choosing the other answer , as it explains more . What you proposed also gets the work done.

Comment: I prefer `bind` instead of a lambda here. What OP is asking for is *exactly* binding an argument.